# Can we move node_modules on static server to build angular application?

Tags: angular, node-modules

Currently, we have node_modules on server (generated after npm install), and when we use `ng build`, build is created with js from node_modules.

My query is, can we move node_modules on static server for angular application?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is deployed and you will run again `npm install`, then yes, you can remove node_modules  folder. As your dependency tree is built and necessary libraries were taken to build js bundle.

**UPDATE:**

If you do not update your `package.json` and do not add new libaries, then you can keep your folder **node_modules** and build your javascript bundle. However, many libraries are updated and sometimes you need to have the most up to date libaries.

Comment: So, can we create a build in future by referring to static server anyway?